# How can I rewrite $\sin(ax)$ as a function of $\sin(bx)$, where: $x,a,b$ are real positive numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> How can I rewrite $\sin(ax)$ as a function of $\sin(bx)$, where: $x,a,b$ are real positive numbers?

For instance, if $y=\sin(ax)$ then $\sin(bx)=f(y)$, but $f$ is a function that use only $+,-,\times,/,{}^\wedge$; in other words I need to represent $\sin(bx)$ by $\sin(ax)$ algebraically.

Comment: Could you give us a concrete example, still not clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most $a$ and $b$, you cannot. Any such function must satisfy $g\left(x+\frac{2\pi}a\right)=g(x)$ for all $x$, while $\sin(bx)$ usually does not.